# indexOf syntax for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

What is the syntax for `indexOf()` to go through a multidimensional array?
For instance:

```
var x = [];
// do something
x.push([a,b]);

x.indexOf(a) // ??
```

I want to find '`a`' and do something with '`b`'. But it does not work... As this method should be iterative itself, I do not presume using any other iteration would be a good thing to do. Currently I simulate this using 2 simple arrays but I guess this should somehow work too...

Comment: Are you trying to create a dictionary? Why not use an object? `{ }`

Comment: Did any of the four suggestions for coding this differently work for you? Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Simply: `indexOf()` does not work this way. It might work if you did something like this:

```
var x = [];
// do something
z = [a,b];
x.push(z);

x.indexOf(z);
```

But then you'd already have z.b wouldn't you? So if you must ignore the advice of everyone who thinks that using an object (or dictionary) is actually easier you'll have to either use [Ates Goral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23501/ates-goral)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427640/indexof-syntax-for-multidimensional-arrays/1428008#1428008), or search for the index yourself:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf0 = 
  function(a){for(i=0;i<this.length;i++)if(a==this[i][0])return i;return null;};
var x = [];
// do something
x.push([a,b]);

x.indexOf0(a); //=> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to preserve order, it's much simpler to use a dictionary:

```
var x = {};

// do something

x[a] = b;
```

You can still iterate over the keys, although the order is undefined:

```
for (var key in x) {
   alert(x[key]);
}
```

Comment: Use x[a] instead of x.a. "a" is not the key name, but the variable that holds the key.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a an object (or dictionary) as Philippe Leybaert suggested. That will allow quick access to elements:

```
var x = {};

x[a] = b; // to set

alert(x[a]) // to access
```

But if you insist on using `indexOf`, there's still a way, however ugly it is:

```
var x = [];

var o = Object(a); // "cast" to an object
o.b = b; // attach value

x.push(o);

alert(x.indexOf(a)); // will give you the index
alert(x[1].b); // access value at given index
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have multidimensional arrays as such, so `x` is merely an array. Also, the `indexOf` method of Array is not supported in all browsers, in particular IE (up to version 7, at least), only being introduced in JavaScript 1.6.

Your only option is to search manually, iterating over `x` and examining each element in turn.

Answer (score 0):

```
x[ x.indexOf(a) ]
```

This will only work with ordered objects/lists and only if Array.prototype.indexOf is defined.

```
x = [1,2], b = {one:function(){alert('gj')}}, c = x.push(b);

x[ x.indexOf( b ) ]['one']()
```

Comment: Well, you must've did it differently because the way I did it works. I did note that this *ONLY* works on arrays that are numerically ordered and have a length property, NOT on "multidimensional" or dictionaries.

Comment: Note - you also need to have a reference to the original object for the reference you're feeding to 'b', a similar object with similar properties is still different.