# Why does this index of a two dimensional array return -1

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
alert( [[0,1],[1,0]].indexOf([0,1]) );
```

And even though the array [0,1] is an element of the two-dimensional array, I get a value of '-1' returned. What have I done wrong in life?

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if the value pair does not exist.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [indexOf syntax for multidimensional arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427640/indexof-syntax-for-multidimensional-arrays) or better [Javascript 2d array indexof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943200/javascript-2d-array-indexof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't find your element because `[0, 1]` and `[0, 1]` are not equal in the same way that `4` and `4` are.

```
console.log(4 === 4); // true
console.log([0, 1] === [0, 1]); // false
```

When you do an equality check for things with a type of `object`, then Javascript uses what's known as [reference equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). It checks whether the two objects are actually the *same instance*.

```
var a = [0, 1];
var b = [1, 0];
var arr = [a, b];

console.log(arr.indexOf(a)); // 0
console.log(a === arr[0]); // true
```

Alternatively you can write your own search function using a [deep equality check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal).

```
function deepSearch(arr, element) {
  for(var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    if(deepEqual(arr[index], element)) {
      return index;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Because **`[0,1] === [0,1]`** is **`false`**.

According to `.indexOf` documentation,

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to `elements` of the Array using **strict equality** (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

You can use a trick and serialize your subarrays and target item.
It works, because `[0,1] !== [0,1]`, but `"[0,1]" === "[0,1]"`:

```js
Array.prototype.indexOfForArrays = function(search)
{
  var searchJson = JSON.stringify(search); // "[0,1]"
  var arrJson = this.map(JSON.stringify); // ["[3,4]", "[0,1]", "[1,0]"]

  return arrJson.indexOf(searchJson);
};

document.body.innerText = [[3,4], [0,1], [1,0]].indexOfForArrays([0,1]);
```

There are some other methods. This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315180/javascript-search-array-of-arrays) may be useful.